# check for EMAIL format in ROW and return value inside SELECT query

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, database

I have a table called user_data and few columns like **LOGIN_NAME**

The column **LOGIN_NAME** may contain "emailformat@email.com" or just a "username"

I need to know if it is possible for me to run a select query and return emailAddress if row has email type format else return userName if it is a non-email format.

example - (I am trying to created a JSON format with this) :

Here signInType is **userName** since Markus Dave is a non-email format (LOGIN_NAME which is a row was having a value Markus Dave ->

```
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "Markus Dave" 
        }
```

Here signInType is **emailAddress** since follyrichard@gmail.com is a email format (LOGIN_NAME which is a row was having a value follyrichard@gmail.com

```
            {
              "signInType": "emailAddress",
              "issuerAssignedId": "follyrichard@gmail.com" 
            }
```

Here is a query that I could produce :

```
SELECT 'signInType' AS signInType
        , LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId
        FROM USER_DATA        
        FOR JSON AUTO;
```

For signInType field, I need to use the same field LOGIN_NAME and check if it is email or not and then prepare according to it.

I have 10 users in the table, I need to create 10 field JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `case` expression:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN LOGIN_NAME LIKE '%@%' THEN 'emailAddress' ELSE 'userName' END) as signInType,
       LOGIN_NAME AS issuerAssignedId
FROM USER_DATA        
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Comment: Is this not a bit broad?  If someone used their twitter handle as a username this would categorise it as an email.  I would think you'd want to expand the like to include at least one character either side, unless the OP knows for a guarantee that no usernames will have an @ character in them

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff, Thanks it worked, I will mark it as an answer, you are a genius

Comment: To indicate an email I would use: "LIKE '%@%.%' AND LEN(LOGIN_NAME)>3